# iptables couldn't load target

Tags: linux, debian, iptables

I am getting this error

**iptables v1.6.0: Couldn't load target `standard':No such file or directory**

Any idea why, and how to solve? The debian version is 9.1

```
(venv)root@deb64:/tmp# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
iptables v1.6.0: Couldn't load target `standard':No such file or directory

Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `iptables` command comes with a whole set of libraries that match the modules, the targets, etc. A message like "Couldn't load target 'FOO'" typically means that the dynamic library corresponding to the target FOO (`iptables -j FOO`) was not found.

But this message is misleading. Debian `iptables` actually comes with a `libxt_standard.so` library and the error message probably means that the library is missing on your machine:

```
# dpkg -L iptables | fgrep standard
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xtables/libxt_standard.so
```

You should probably reinstall `iptables`:

```
apt-get install --reinstall iptables
```